# Prove that $e^x \gt 0$ for $x \in \mathbb{R}$

Tags: exponential-function

This is a consequence of the exponential rule, but how do I actually prove it to be true?

Comment: $$x>-\infty\implies a^x>a^{-\infty}$$ for real $a>1$

Comment: How do you define $e^x$ ?

Comment: $e$ is a positive number. Think about what happens when you multiply a positive number by a positive number.

Comment: what is its inverse ?

Answer (score 3):

How do you define $e^x$?

The most common way to define it is

$$e^x = \sum_{n = 0}^{\infty} \frac{x^n}{n!}$$

If you take this definition, then if $x > 0$, $e^x$ is the sum of an infinite number of positive terms.

One should show that the series converges, but if you take that for granted, then of course if converges to a positive number.

If $x < 0$ then $e^{-x} > 0$ ; and since $$ e^x \cdot e^{-x} = 1 > 0 \Rightarrow e^x > 0$$ since $e^{-x} > 0$

Comment: Your approach lacks to study the behavior of $e^{x}$ for $x<0$. Any idea on how to do it using simple considerations ?

Comment: @jibe ops I misread the question! I edited :-) Thanks to both of you for pointing that out :-)

Answer (score 3):

Every definition of $\exp(x)$ leads to the property, $\exp(a+b)= \exp(a)\exp(b)$. Furthermore every definition also tells us that $\exp$ is defined on the entire real line and takes real values when given a real number as an argument.

So we will consider the exponential function evaluated at $x$ and notice that$x=x/2+x/2$.

$$ \exp(x) = \exp(x/2)\exp(x/2) = (\exp(x/2))^2 > 0 $$

Since the square of every real number is positive we have our result.

Comment: See also http://math.stackexchange.com/a/626856/589.

Comment: @lhf, your version is much better. I didn't think to check the case possibility that $exp(x/2)=0$. This question should probably be closed as duplicate.

Comment: @Osama, your edit was inappropriate. Please refrain from trying to edit my answer again. If you have a recommendation to make then you may comment on my answer.

Answer (score 1):

We have that $e>0$. Then for every $n\in \Bbb N$ we have that $e^n>0$.Because $\sqrt[m] .$ is increasing then $\sqrt [m] {e^n}>0$. Thus $$e^q>0$$ for every $q\in \Bbb Q$. Now $\Bbb Q$ is dense in $\Bbb R$ thus $e^x>0$ for every $x\in \Bbb R$.